# Kotlin JDBC trying connect to mssqlserver with SSL sertificate and got error

Tags: sql-server, kotlin, exception, ssl, jdbc

I'm trying to use *com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.2.0.jre11* driver which is recommended for direct mssql connection from kotlin android app. Before I used JDTS and it worked for me but with JDBC 12.2.0 i got next error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:The driver was unable to establish
a secure connection to SQL Server using SSL encryption. Error: "Socket is closed".
```

My implementation on build.gradle is

```
implementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.2.0.jre11"
```

Connection string

```
val connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.56:1433;databaseName=akhasap_db;user=sa;password=123456;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;"
```

Code for connection

```
try {
       println("Connecting to SQL Server ... $connectionUrl")
       DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl).use { connection -> println("Done.") }
       Snackbar.make(view, "Connected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
       Snackbar.make(view, "Can't Connect to DB", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show()
       println("DkPrintError:"+e.toString())
       e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

In that phone I use RemoDb to test connection and it works. I mean, its not a problem with remote sqlserver db configuration. Only my app can't connect to mssql server. I want to connect without SSL. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Is the SQL Server instance configured to *require* encrypted connections?

Comment: Does it help to completely remove trustserverCertificate?

Comment: SqlServer Configuration Manager - > SQL server Network configuration -> Protocols for SQLSERVER properties->Named Pipes -> Force Encription = "false", but it doesnt help

Comment: RE "....and gots error": What error are you getting?

Comment: For connections without SSL Configuration Manager-> Network Configuration->Protocols for (your instance)->Right-click TCP/IP->Properties->Security tab->Clear Require SSL

Comment: Why would you be trying to connect directly to a database from the app? Seems dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

### Quick Checklist for TLS issues

- SQL Server should be fully patched to ensure TLS 1.2 support.
- SQL Server's OS should be fully patched.
- Java runtime should be moderately recent... (i.e. not java6).
- Pick one of the following:

  - use "TrustServerCertificate="true"
  - Install a trusted certificate on the SQL Server
- "encrypt=true" in the connection string is a safe bet, and can help protect against issues in the future.  *Since encryption can always be forced by the server, **"encrypt=false" should never be considered a "fix" for TLS issues***

### Background Info

SQL Server uses TLS in two scenarios regarding client connections:

1. The entire connection is encrypted.  This can be **requested** by the client (encrypt=true;) or **enforced** by the server.  The client default for encryption depends on the driver version.  JDBC 10.2 or later encrypts by default. (Other drivers like ODBC, .Net, etc. changed default behavior around the same time).
2. TLS is also used during the login process to protect the username/password.  This usage is forced and not affected by any connection string settings or server configuration options.  (i.e., SQL server will **always** use TLS to protect the password.)

SQL Server **DOES NOT** have an internal TLS implementation. It uses the TLS libraries from the OS  (SCHANNEL for windows, openssl? for linux). The means TLS support in SQL Server can be affected by OS version/patches as well as SQL Server version/patches.

The Java runtime **DOES** have an internal TLS implementation.

TLS requires certificates for authentication.  These are the same type of certs used for https. If you don't install a certificate on SQL Server, it will self-generate one.  This self-generated certificate will not be trusted by clients.

Whether the client is picky about the server certificate and validates it or not is also driver version dependent.  Jdbc 10.2 introduced a breaking change, and attempts to validate the certificate in more scenarios.  TrustServerCertificate=true tells the driver to bypass certificate validation.

### Additional Considerations

The checklist above will address 95% of SQL Server TLS issues.  If you are still experiencing issues, then it's a matter of confirming which of the two usage scenarios are involved.

- Scenario 1 is usually certificate related, or can be affected by a connection string change.
- scenario 2 (user/password) implies either TLS version mismatch or OS <-> Java cipher suite issues.  certificates/ cert validation are not involved in the login process.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Because it's coming weekend, I don't have the possibility to test it (I forgot VPN :-) ), so if this doesn't help, I will reopen the issue in the future. But, I hope your complete answer really works.